# Interning longs

Tags: python, string-interning

Python's `intern` function lets you save memory if you have a lot of copies of the same string floating around, by replacing them all with references to a single object.

I have a similar situation, except that instead of strings I'm dealing with `long`s.

Is there a way to do something similar with `long`s?

Comment: 2.7. The docs don't say anything about deprecation, although I'm aware the function was moved to the `sys` module in Python 3.

Comment: AFAIK no. You could simply keep a `dict` and whenever you want to replace a `long` by its unique representation replace it with the value in the `dict`. Note however that you really must have a lot of *very* big `long`s with many repetitions to save significant memory.